# Accessing div id to addClass after JQuery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery drag and drop and trying to addClass to a div after drop.  adding the class works OK before drop but not after.  How can I access the dropped div to addClass where:

```
function play_vid(){
    $("#v1").show();
    v1.play();
    $("#element_1").addClass('highlighted');
}
```

Which comes after:

```
function handleElementDrop( event, ui ) {

  var slotNumber = $(this).data( 'number' );
  var elementNumber = ui.draggable.data( 'number' );

  if ( slotNumber == elementNumber ) {



ui.draggable.css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );

setTimeout(function(){
ui.draggable.find('.element_left').click(function(e) {  
        window.open(ui.draggable.attr('data-link'));
    });
    });

ui.draggable.parent().find('.info').addClass('correct');      
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );

    slots_filled.push(ui.draggable.data('number')) 

    if(slots_filled.length == slots){
play_vid();
  }
  } 
}
```

See Fifddle http://jsfiddle.net/f3Kgj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is no element with id `element_1`, you are changing the `id` to `element1`.

so change

```
function play_vid(){
    $("#v1").show();
    v1.play();
    $("#element1").addClass('highlighted');
}
```

Comment: Thanks...should read the code more.  Also had to remove the previously added class $("#element1").removeClass('correct');